# Error in RStudioGD() : Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to plot using Rstudio. But when I do, `plot(cars)` which is the basic function, I am getting an `Graphics Error in R`.
Here is what I have done :

```
> plot(cars)
Error in RStudioGD() : 
  Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)
```

Please guide me through.

Comment: Above link is broken.

Comment: This problem pop up now and then with different version of R. It seems that using R 3.4.2 and Rstudio 1.1.442 (both latest for ubuntu:16.04) the problem occurs again. Any real solution different than waiting for the next update is welcome

Answer (score 5):

Thank goodness, I just exited Rstudio and relaunched and the problem went away

Answer (score 5):

Solution for error:

```
Error in RStudioGD() :

  Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)
```

In R Studio, navigate to <kbd>Tools</kbd>, <kbd>Global</kbd>, <kbd>Graphics</kbd> (top middle), set <kbd>Backend</kbd> to `AGG`*, <kbd>Apply</kbd>, <kbd>Ok</kbd>

*Depending on your system/installation, you may have other other options in the drop down. Ex. `AGG`, `Cairo`, `Cairo PNG`.

**AGG** is a package which provides graphic devices for R based on the AGG library developed by the late Maxim Shemanarev. AGG provides both higher performance and higher quality than the standard raster devices provided by grDevices. You might need to install AGG. Compatible with R Studio since v1.4.

https://ragg.r-lib.org/

Comment: This solution worked for me using RStudio Server 2022.02.2+485 "Prairie Trillium" Release (8acbd38b0d4ca3c86c570cf4112a8180c48cc6fb, 2022-04-19) for Ubuntu Bionic.

Comment: This worked for me and is the easiest solution I think. I run RStudio 2022.07.1 Build 554

Comment: This worked for me RStudio Prairie Trillium + compiled version of R 4.2 development version "Unsuffered Consequences" '2022-08-19_r82735' in Fedora 36

Comment: This worked for me using `R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) | Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`. Thank you very much for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

Initially, I reinstalled RStudio to the newest version (1.1.442) and, following many advice also the R-base* system (getting to R 3.4.3) using aptitude in the following way:

`sudo aptitude reinstall libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpango-1.0-0 
sudo aptitude reinstall r-base r-base-core r-base-dev`

I used aptitude because it is usually better than apt-get to disentangle intricate dependency trees. Afterwards, when no package was loaded into the environment it was working just fine but any package loading was creating a whole variety of DLL-related errors as follows.

FINAL SOLUTION (NO NEED OF REINSTALL):

The error was showing again as soon as I loaded my self-made library. The real problem is the number of open DLL. If you load too many packages or files you will get to the limit and you will have error messages between `maximal number of DLLs reached...` or `failed to load cairo DLL` (this error warning) or even `lapack routines  cannot be loaded`. I had these three error randomly as I loaded my full-of-dependencies-homemade-library.

So I started again looking for a solution. The final one is to allow more DLL and to do so it is enough to set the environmental variable `R_MAX_NUM_DLLS` to a higher number (I set it to 500). In order to avoid the hassle of setting it every time you can read `?Startup` documentation and consequently write `R_MAX_NUM_DLLS=500` in your Renviron file `R-HOME/etc/Renviron.site`. In my case (Ubuntu:16.04 it was `/usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron.site`. This fixed smoothly the problem.

Comment: It is also possible that you are using `homebrew` and `apt-get` together. As I do that and the error appeared again, I thought it was due to a possible collision between the two versions. If that is also your case, doing a `brew unlink` on cairo and pango could be enough to solve the version mismatch (or you go fully brew and delete the apt-get ones).

Answer (score 2):

Under Ubuntu 13.10
I had the similar issue with rstudio server, tried all different suggestions no work.
Finally figured out this way:

1. `sudo service rstudio-server stop`
2. remove all rstudio related files (`sudo find / -name "rstudio" | xargs sudo rm -r`)
3. uninstall R: `sudo apt-get remove r-base-core r-base r-base-dev`
4. remove all R related files (`sudo find / -name "R" | xargs sudo rm -r`)
5. re-install R: `sudo apt-get install r-base-core r-base r-base-dev`
6. test R: making sure plot(cars) works in R, output a pdf file.
7. re-install R studio server: http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/server

Comment: This solution was not effective in my case and it is a huge loss of time if you have many packages installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found James Mao's answer helpful, but I wanted to avoid reinstalling R so that I would not have to also reinstall all of my R packages. I was able to fix the issue by reinstalling RStudio without reinstalling R, which makes sense because the error is with RStudio, not R itself. Here are the instructions:

1. `sudo service rstudio-server stop`
2. remove all rstudio related files (`sudo find / -name "rstudio" | xargs sudo rm -r`)
3. re-install R studio server: http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/server

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the package ggplot2 (install.packages"ggplot2") and invoke the library. It must work then

Answer (score 0):

I meet this today, reindatall Rstudio still can't solve. finally installed textshaping
install.packages('textshaping'). It's ok now

Answer (score -1):

I had the following error in a CentOS:7 Docker container when running `rstudio-server verify-installation`:

```
27 Feb 2017 14:17:09 [rsession-rstudio-server] ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=Error in system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) :
  error in running command
]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::r::exec::<unnamed>::evaluateExpressionsUnsafe(SEXPREC*, SEXPREC*, SEXPREC**, rstudio::r::sexp::Protect*, rstudio::r::exec::<unnamed>::EvalType) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:159; LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::FilePath rstudio::session::module_context::findProgram(const std::string&) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionModuleContext.cpp:879
27 Feb 2017 14:17:09 [rsession-rstudio-server] ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=Error in system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) :
  error in running command
]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::r::exec::<unnamed>::evaluateExpressionsUnsafe(SEXPREC*, SEXPREC*, SEXPREC**, rstudio::r::sexp::Protect*, rstudio::r::exec::<unnamed>::EvalType) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:159; LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::FilePath rstudio::session::module_context::findProgram(const std::string&) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionModuleContext.cpp:879
```

I fixed it by installing `which` command: `yum install which`

Comment: It seems to me that this is an unrelated error. This problem and its solution do not seem to be DLL-related or RStudioGD()/ graphics related

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error and am on Ubuntu. I did not install R through `sudo apt-get install r-base` but instead downloaded a specific [version](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/), unpacked it and installed it manually with:

```
./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no --enable-R-shlib
make
sudo make install
```

I did not have cairograpghics installed, which is apparently important to build 2D graphics with R. So I installed that with:

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
```

Or find the version for your OS here: https://www.cairographics.org/download/

I then uninstalled R again by simply going into the downloaded R folder that I had previously compiled using the above commands mentioned and typed:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

And then I configured and installed the same R version again. That did it. The uninstall and reinstall was important, just installing cairographics didnt work, you have to have it installed before using `./configure`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem (even though I had been using the same installation for over a year without this problem). 
I just needed to restart the computer and everything was good again. 
:D

Comment: Not actually the answer. You should have commented instead of answer.