# Error in plot function on Rstudio server: Error in RStudioGD() : Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)

Tags: r, ubuntu, plot, rstudio

So I know that this has been asked and answered before on stack overflow but the answers havent solved my problem, so Im hoping there have been new findings with this issue and somebody could help me with it.

I am running RStudio on Ubuntu 12.04 lts and with R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14). When I try to use the plot function I get the following errro msg:

```
> plot(cars)
Error in RStudioGD() : 
  Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

warnings() gives me:

```
Warning messages:
1: In grDevices:::png("/tmp/RtmpOdYXyC/1ec8e69b4b2b4902818e02cd828dbf5e.png",  ... :
  failed to load cairo DLL
2: In grDevices:::png("/tmp/RtmpOdYXyC/a4885ae9c7b846698a638ca9c65e2632.png",  ... :
  failed to load cairo DLL
3: In grDevices:::png("/tmp/RtmpOdYXyC/91faf2840f694bef8d04409cdc64e5c9.png",  ... :
  failed to load cairo DLL
4: In grDevices:::png("/tmp/RtmpOdYXyC/4f77d036b3bc4e9f815d1aa8c8d834da.png",  ... :
  failed to load cairo DLL
5: In grDevices:::png("/tmp/RtmpOdYXyC/e2f473f06d904168ab34a3efb0793389.png",  ... :
  failed to load cairo DLL
6: In grDevices:::png("/tmp/RtmpOdYXyC/6904947cbaac4bec835e3d6c3c7beffb.png",  ... :
  failed to load cairo DLL

> capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE
```

I was previously running Rstudio with the r-base software downloaded from the ubuntu software center and never faced this problem.

Since I needed to download a few packages that were not supported by that version I decided to download the latest version(3.2.2) from my browser so I could download the packages needed.

Now I am not being able to use a simple function like plot. I have gone through stack and seen that many people have faced this problem but I havent come across a solution to my problem yet. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything like one of the answers said but that didn't work for me, I am still getting the same error.

Lot of forums have asked for the following:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_IN.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_IN.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_IN.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_IN.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_IN.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] highfrequency_0.4 xts_0.9-7         zoo_1.7-12       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2     grid_3.2.2      lattice_0.20-33
> capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE 
> png(); dev.off()
Error in png() : X11 module cannot be loaded
> x11()
Error in x11() : X11 module cannot be loaded
> Sys.getenv("DISPLAY")
[1] ":0.0"
```

Can someone please shed some light on this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you require anymore information.

Comment: Are you using the newest RStudio release? If yes, you should take this to the RStudio support forum.

Comment: Also, have you installed cairo?

Comment: Yes to both questions. And I was just about to take to the support forum.

Comment: Are you able to access the Cairo device in a vanilla R session (ie, no RStudio)? Perhaps Cairo needs to be (re)installed?

Comment: problem has been solved. Thanks

Comment: @Ayush How was this solved.

Comment: @Hedgehog I literally just deleted everything R related on my computer and re-installed it again and it worked for me. I think the problem came when I updated R version, there was some problem in the installation process.

Comment: Is there a way without reinstalling everything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in RStudioGD() : Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513705/error-in-rstudiogd-shadow-graphics-device-error-r-error-4-r-code-execution)