# Error in RStudioGD(): Shadow graphics device error: r error 4

Tags: r, graphics, rstudio, device

I updated my R to the latest version of 3.4.2, and when I used `plot()` or `ggplot()` to draw graphics, RStudio showed the message:

> Error in RStudioGD() :    Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)

I have tried the methods mentioned before, but it didn't work, and then I came back to the old version of 3.3.2, everything was ok! So I need some help to figure out the problems. My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: First, thank Konrad Rudolph for editing my question! And today I tried different R version of 3.3.3,  both on win10-64bit and win7-32bit, only when using 3.4.2 will the problem appears, so I think maybe it is the latest version bug!

Comment: For me this is working in R console, broken in RStudio.

Comment: I have this same issue..... I have tried a fresh re-install of all components, including R and rstudio. I have tried a manual installation of all the missing components (Cairo, pango).... and still nothing. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This problem has (for me) other drawbacks, such as impossibility to load lapack.so and so on. Any news on this question would be super appreaciated (I am on ubuntu:16.04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in RStudioGD() : Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513705/error-in-rstudiogd-shadow-graphics-device-error-r-error-4-r-code-execution)